# add a temp gauge or "dimmer" to cabinet fan

Tags: cabinets, fans, cooling

I have an AC cabinet fan cooling a cabinet that warms with 2 CPUs and a couple external hard drives in it that are on 24/7.

However, the fan runs furiously fast and loud and it only really needs to draw a steady flow of air into the cabinet.

I'm wondering if there is a safe way to add either:

1. a thermostat of some kind that will turn the fan on and off when temp exceeds a certain temperature 'zone'.
2. a 'dimmer' or voltage regulator I could put inline that would dial back the speed of this fan.
3. both?

The fan is a 115v US Toyo Fan (model: [ustf80381153w](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088WLPTW)).

Answer (score 2):

They make much quieter fans for this. There are many how-to guides out there on how to do entertainment center exhaust fan systems. You can google [Entertainment center exhaust fan](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=TFazVKGHHIn8oQTw8oK4Bg&ved=0CAcQ1S4#q=entertainment+center+exhaust+fan) and see some pretty slick designs. There were a couple that were 'automated'

If you are using 120v you could always get a Attic Fan Thermostat and connect it inline with the Fan Power. something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002TYK4A6) unit. It is settable from 50 degrees to 120 Degrees. Or something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000E7BTFO) if you want it to look nice outside of the cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a motor speed control, but you have to check the specs to see if it will work with your fan. I'm not knowledgeable enough in the area to tell you, other than to tell you it exists.

A thermostat controlled relay is quite easy - you can buy a simple 120v relay and attach it to a standard home thermostat. Or buy something smaller made for it.